# Change Content like google?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a help page with a similar layout as http://support.google.com/plus/?hl=en. Could someone please give me some advice or example of the best way to get the new content list to load without having to reload the page.

If you look at the link and press on for example, "circles and streams it changes the list on the right hand side.

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

well for the purpose you can use the library jQuery.  [VISIT Here](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/) for documentation of jquery. also plz go through css3 and html5 features as these provide immense tools for formatting such as float, position, display etc..

or else no external library
 you can simply use the css3 and html5 properties to create tableless layouts.

**html**

```
<div style="width: 100%;">
            <div style="float: left; width:50%; height: 200px;background-color:Yellow;">
               <input type="button" onclick="asd(1)" value="one" />
               <input type="button" onclick="asd(2)" value="two" />
               <input type="button" onclick="asd(3)" value="three" />
            </div>
            <div id="one" style="float: left; width: 110px;height:200px;display:none; background-color:Blue;">
                Cell 2
            </div>
            <div id="two" style="float:left;width: 110px;height:200px;background-color:Red; display:none;">
                Cell 3
            </div>
            <div id="three" style="float:left; width: 110px;height:200px;;background-color:Green; display:none;">
                Cell 4
            </div>
        </div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function asd(a)
{
    document.getElementById("one").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("two").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("three").style.display="none";
    if(a==1)
    document.getElementById("one").style.display="block";
    if(a==2)
    document.getElementById("two").style.display="block";
    if(a==3)
    document.getElementById("three").style.display="block";
}
```

now place the contents of the divs as according to your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Check bootstrap from Twitter. http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/. you can easily create the layout and controls. Check the examples.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how much content you want to show on your page, but the way I would do this is using javascript to show and hide the relevant sections. Here is a jsfiddle showing a simple example http://jsfiddle.net/am2Dm/10/.

If you have a large amount of data, or perhaps dynamic data, you might want to consider shooting off AJAX calls to retrieve your content lists - but this is likely overkill.

Answer (score 0):

Plenty of Javascript tools exist that can aid you in doing this. The two that are likely the most commonly used are Mootools and jQuery. Try using one of those, they both come with plenty of examples and tutorials that should help you complete this task.

Comment: Agreed, but as this is an extremely basic question so a framework makes more since in my opinion as the OP is obviously not experienced with Javascript and the frameworks have very good documentation with plenty of examples for exactly this situation. Also given the vagueness of the question I felt it was inappropriate to just write the code for the OP as there would be no learning or improvement going that route, I see others disagree.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (no framwork required):

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="javascript:loadList('Games')">Games</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:loadList('Music')">Music</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:loadList('Videos')">Videos</a></li>
</ul>

<ul id="targetList"></ul>

<script type="text/javascript">

var list = {
    Games: [
        { name: 'Warcraft III', href: 'http://www.blizzard.net' },
        { name: 'Warcraft III', href: 'http://www.blizzard.net' },
        { name: 'Warcraft III', href: 'http://www.blizzard.net' }
        ],
    Music: [
        { name: 'Madonna', href: 'http://www.madonna.com' },
        { name: 'Madonna', href: 'http://www.madonna.com' },
        { name: 'Madonna', href: 'http://www.madonna.com' }
        ],
    Videos: [
        { name: 'Youtube', href: 'http://www.youtube.com' },
        { name: 'Youtube', href: 'http://www.youtube.com' },
        { name: 'Youtube', href: 'http://www.youtube.com' }
        ]
    };

function loadList(index) {

    var targetList = document.getElementById("targetList");
    targetList.innerHTML = "";

    for(var i = 0; i < list[index].length; i++) {
        var li = document.createElement('li');
            var a = document.createElement('a');
                a.href = list[index][i].href;
                a.innerHTML = list[index][i].name;
            li.appendChild(a);
        targetList.appendChild(li);
        }

    }

loadList('Games');

</script>
```